# Custom exception handler not outputting

Tags: laravel, api

I'm trying to output custom exceptions for my API:

**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException) {
        return response()->json([
            'code' => $exception->getCode(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ]);
    }
    $response = $this->handleException($request, $exception);
    return $response;
}

public function handleException($request, Exception $exception)
{

    if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        return $this->errorResponse('The specified method for the request is invalid', 405);
    }

    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        //return $this->errorResponse('The specified URL cannot be found', 404);

        dd('woo');
    }

    if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
        return $this->errorResponse($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getStatusCode());
    }

    if (config('app.debug')) {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);            
    }
    return $this->errorResponse('Unexpected Exception. Try later', 500);

}
```

Right now I am trying to test the exception handler by querying an id that doesn't exist in my controller:

```
public function processCheckout(Request $request)
{    
    
    //Id 100 doesn't exist
    $plan = Plan::findOrFail(100);
    $user = $user = auth()->user();
    
    //If user has no subscriptions subscribe them to new plan
    if($user->subscriptions->count() === 0){
        $user->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->stripe_plan_id)->create($request->payment_method['id']);

        //return response([], 201);
    }
}
```

Instead of laravel throwing the exception I've put in the handler I keep getting no exception at all. When I turn on debug, the exception doesn't seem to be being caught in the render method:

```
{
    "message": "No query results for model [App\\Plan] 100",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
}
```

How do I get this to work and implement my own custom message? this being:

```
if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
    //return $this->errorResponse('The specified URL cannot be found', 404);

    dd('woo');
}
```

Comment: Have you imported the `NotFoundHttpException`?

Comment: Yes, I have:

`use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason when a model is not for the  exception message says it's a `NotFoundHttpException`. As you can see in this part of the response above:

```
{
    "message": "No query results for model [App\\Plan] 100",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
}
```

The real exception is a model not found exception:

**At the Top**

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;`

**In render method**

```
if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Entry for '.str_replace('App\\', '', $exception->getModel()).' not found'], 404);
}
```